# Proper way of returning a functor in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, functor, function-object

Consider we have an `add` function declared like this:

```cpp
int add(const int a, const int b);
```

If we were to return this `add` function from `foo`...

```cpp
std::function<int(const int, const int)> foo()
{
    return add;
}
```

```cpp
std::function<int(const int, const int)> foo()
{
    return &add;
}
```

Which one of the above is the correct way of returning a function object since both work exactly the same?

Comment: Also consider `auto foo() -> int(&)(int, int) { return add; }`, where `&add` just doesn't work so there is a "correct" way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both code snippets are identical (as far as the language is concerned).

`std::function` can be constructed from any callable object (whether it be a lambda, pointer-to-function, etc). In both examples, you are constructing the `std::function` with a function pointer.

- In the first example, `add` denotes the name of a function -- which decays to a function pointer.
- In the second example, the expression`&add` explicitly takes the address of a function, producing a function pointer.

There is no "correct" convention as each are equally valid. What matters most in a code-base is consistency and readability; so I'd stick to whatever practice the existing code-base uses, or whichever practice is dictated in your organization's coding conventions.

Comment: I know that they are the same, but what is the generally accepted convention when doing this kind of thing?

Comment: There is no explicitly accepted convention (and in fact, such a question is off-topic for Stack-Overflow since it's opinion-based). Different organizations may have different preferences on convention, and any such convention may be equally valid.

Comment: I disagree that this question is off-topic. This particular question might not have an objective answer but for many other cases where one of the two (or many) functionally identical syntax is considered the "best-practice". I cannot know if its answer is "doesn't matter" or not, without asking.

Comment: I'd suggest adding "There is no explicitly accepted convention" sentence to the answer text.

Comment: I can add that to the answer, though the phrasing of the question does not make it clear that its asking about convention (which is why I have not added this yet). As for whether it's off-topic or not: just about anything that may be convention-based is generally off-topic, especially in C++ that does not have any standard coding conventions. What matters most is consistency.

Comment: Notice that conversion from function to function pointer inherit from C, for member pointer, there are no implicit conversion and `&` is required (`&MyClass::foo`), if it might guide about convention.